# Marketing Cloud - Using Triggered Sends

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect

In our Org, we are using apex to send outbound email for various use cases. But, we are hitting ***Single Email Limit Exceeded Error*** during some busy days.

We do use Marketing Cloud separately, I was wondering if any one used its **Triggered Sends** through Marketing Cloud Connect to replace Apex (Messaging.SingleEmailMessage) to bypass the 5000/Day apex email limit.

If Yes, I would love to know how you accomplished it.

Comment: One way that does not involve MC Connect is to simply [call the REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45471/exact-target-triggered-send-using-salesforce-apex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s pretty straight forward when you’re using Marketing Cloud Connect.

Here’s an overview:

1. First, set the email up in Marketing Cloud. You can follow any available Email Studio tutorial to achieve that.
2. Enable Triggered Sends: In Sales/Service Cloud, switch to the Salesforce Classic UI, navigate to the Marketing Cloud tab and click on Configure Marketing Cloud Connector. Scroll down to Triggered Sends and in the Enabled Object section, add the required object to the list.
3. After you save the settings, once again navigate to the Marketing Cloud tab and click on Triggered Sends. In the Triggered Sends Management section, click on New. Enter a Name for your triggered send and choose an Object to use with the Triggered Sends.
4. Next, find the Email that you created earlier and choose the Send Classification, a Sender Profile if needed and a Triggered Data Extension for logging the send results. Leave the Disable Individual Level Tracking box unchecked, choose immediate Send Time and who the Error Notifications be sent to. Check the box that says I certify all of these people will have opted in and I certify all of these people will have opted in and click on Save.
5. Then, set up a trigger, here’s an example for a CampainMember object:

   `trigger Trig_CampaignMember on CampaignMember (after insert, after update){ et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('CampaignMember'); }`

The detailed guide with all steps necessary in both Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud can be found here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/25/introduction-to-triggered-sends/

Comment: Any Idea how it will impact API usage ? I mean, API calls made by Marketing Cloud are from Org's quota right?

Comment: See if this helps: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340150&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1 and https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_understand_triggered_sends.htm&type=5